# macOS - Move mouse by value

Tags: swift, macos

I have an app that receives data from an iOS app through bluetooth and it is supposed to move the mouse cursor.

The problem is that I get some weird functionality at y axis (x is fine).

The input looks like `dx~dy` where dx,dy are the values to move the cursor by. Here is an example:

***-3.0~2.0***

An example of my output:

***Mouse loc: (596.0, 309.0) New Mouse loc: (603.0, 311.0)***

***Mouse loc: (603.0, 489.0) New Mouse loc: (610.0, 491.0)***

***Mouse loc: (610.0, 309.0) New Mouse loc: (615.0, 311.5)***

***Mouse loc: (615.0, 489.0) New Mouse loc: (618.0, 491.0)***

***Mouse loc: (618.0, 309.0) New Mouse loc: (618.5, 312.5)***

As you can see first it has a lower *y* coordinate than a higher one. So basically the mouse keeps "*jumping*" up and down.

Here is my code that handles the input:

```
let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation()
let newLoc = CGPoint(x: mouseLoc.x-CGFloat(x), y: mouseLoc.y+CGFloat(y))
CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(0, newLoc)
```

EDIT: in the test case I had values between 0 and 2 so there is no way to have a difference of 100 between two states

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cocoa and Core Graphics (a.k.a. Quartz) use different coordinate systems. In Cocoa, the origin is at the lower left of the primary screen and y increases as you go up.  In Core Graphics, the origin is at the top left of the primary screen and y increases as you go down.

Since you're using a Core Graphics function to move the cursor, you need to convert from Cocoa's coordinate system.

```
var mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation()
mouseLoc.y = NSHeight(NSScreen.screens()![0].frame) - mouseLoc.y;
// etc.
```

Comment: This would make the mouse Move invers, wouldn't it? In my case it jumps up and down and I can not move it along the y axis

Comment: Let's assume that you don't add/subtract anything from the coords. If you simply do `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(0, CGPoint(x: mouseLoc.x, y: mouseLoc.y))` after the code I showed, then this will not move the cursor at all. It doesn't "inverse" it or anything. It's setting it to exactly where it already is. The modification to `mouseLoc.y` doesn't *move* the position, it converts it from one coordinate system to another. It's the same exact position, just expressed in a different coordinate system as appropriate for the function you're calling.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand :) I know this kind of problems with different coordinate systems. But when you , for example, do some 2D graphics and you change the c.system you points just get mirrored to the horizontal center of the screen and not start to jump up and down like my cursor did.. but anyways, it works so Thx :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked. :) It was jumping up and down because you were accidentally flipping vertically. You were getting a y which was the distance from the bottom and then setting it as the distance from the top. Then, the next time, you were flipping it again, which more or less put it back where it was before the first time. Then, repeat again and again.